# mySQL: pattern matching 'one condition or the other but not both'

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I am trying to craft code that "Shows the countries that are big by *area* or big by *population* but *not both*". It should show the name, population and area.

***The table the code references...***

[image: Table the code references]

***This is my code so far...***

```
SELECT name, population, area FROM world
WHERE area > 3000000 OR population > 250000000 OR name != LIKE '%United States%'
```

`world` contains `name`, `area`, and `population`.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: link for the original test: https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`XOR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_xor) for this. It's true if only one of its parameters is true.

```
SELECT name, population, area
FROM world
WHERE (area > 3000000 XOR population > 250000000) 
    AND name NOT LIKE '%United States%'
```

I also changed the way the `United States` test is combined. I assume you're trying to exclude United States from the results, so it needs to be `AND`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `XOR` (exclusive OR) operator:

```
SELECT name, population, area FROM world
WHERE area > 3000000 XOR population > 250000000
```